# How to use Jmeter with timer

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am having a problem with the JMETER, using it with Timer causes Crash to the Jmeter
The case is : I want to create a load of requests to be executed every half hour

Is that something you can do with Jmeter?

every-time i try it it causes Jmeter to keep loading and hangs and require a shut down

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the error and any log?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave JMeter up and running forever make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as certain test elements might cause [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

If you need to create "spikes" of load each 30 minutes it might be a better idea to consider your operating system scheduling mechanisms to execute "short" tests each half an hour like:

- [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)
- [Unix cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
- [MacOS launchd](https://www.launchd.info/)

Or even better go for Continuous Integration server like [Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins/), it has the most powerful trigger mechanism allowing defining flexible criteria regarding when to start the job and you can also benefit from the [Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/) which allows automatically marking build as unstable or failed depending on test metrics and building performance trend charts